# ffprobe exec on video files causes error - not caught in tests

Tags: api, go, ffprobe

I've created a cmd exec to be run from an input video file (mov+mp4 tried), that's being created as a temporary file:

```
cmd := exec.Command(ffprobe, "-v", "error", "-print_format", "json", "-show_format", "-show_streams", "-hide_banner", fileName)
```

When I run the functions as a test, the ffprobe cmd works fine, but when I create the request from http, the cmd fails with msg:

> /var/folders/b1/53jz_b9j1rb0nhhzmv4kwbk80000gn/T/prefix-044409485: Invalid data found when processing input

I read the file as an `io.Reader` both in the http request and the testing func, so the input datatype should be identical.

What should happen: the http request will return the same output as the test func.

What do you think causes it? The temporary file is being created perfectly, but I'm having doubts whether the http request body add's some metadata to the file upon the request.
Other thought is the "moov atom" issue in mp4 files.

Comment: What's the command to generate the files?

Comment: Just stdlib:
`file, err := ioutil.TempFile(os.TempDir(), "prefix-*")`
`_ := ioutil.WriteFile(file.Name(), data, 0777)`.

Comment: Where does the payload come from (the MP4)?

Comment: payload is a r.Body from http.HandlerFunc. Check here: https://github.com/blixenkrone/gopro/blob/video-width-height/internal/server/handlers.go#L199

Comment: @Gyan this is the pkg running exec: https://github.com/blixenkrone/gopro/blob/video-width-height/internal/exif/video/video.go#L104